# getting the value from data table with checkbox codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatable, datatables

I am working with my project in school. How can i get the value of selected checkbox in data table. I am using a codeigniter framework and i am populating my data table in controller and passed it to the view. Now i want to something alert/output the user_id of the checked data table. What i really want is to save the values of the checked user_id in my database table.

Here is my controller for populating the data table:

```
public function getalldocs() 
    $listdocs = $this->Admin_model->getdoctors();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($listdocs as $docs) {
        $row = array();  
        $row[] = $docs->user_fname;
        $row[] = $docs->user_mname;
        $row[] = $docs->user_lname;
        $row[] = '<input name="user_id[]" value=" "'.$docs->user_id.'" " type="checkbox">';

        $data[] = $row;
    }
    $output = array(   
        "data" => $data,
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

in my view, here is the ajax for data table:

```
function show_docs() {
    $("#dataTables-docs").dataTable().fnDestroy();

    table =  $('#dataTables-docs').DataTable({ 
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('admin_controls/getalldocs')?>",
             "type": "POST",
        },
        responsive: true,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        'bInfo': false,
        'paging': false
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-docs').dataTable();
    show_docs();
});
```

Comment: You could do that by adding class name for the checkbox and binding an event to the checkbox when it is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get data from `row` table using this code:

```
$('#dataTables-docs tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){

  var row = $(this).closest('tr');
  var data = table.row(row).data();
  var rowData = data[1];

  alert(rowData);

});
```

Return the data of row selected from checkbox, if you want get the value of checkbox (`user_id`), then you can use this code:

```
$('#dataTables-docs tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){

  var user_id = $(this).val();
  alert(user_id);

});
```

**Result:** https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/130/

Comment: hello sir.. it displays empty?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/130/ check when you select the checkbox display alert with the data and user_id

Comment: my code differs from it, i put the value of user_id from my controller not in my view?

Comment: if you put the value in your controller, its render in the view, then my second code sholud working!

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  var getcheck = $('#dataTables-docs').dataTable();

  $('#dataTables-docs').dataTable();
  show_docs();

  $('#dataTables-docs').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){
      
      var row = $(this).closest('tr');
      var data = oTable.row(row).data();
      var rowData = data[1];
      
      var user_id = $(this).val();
      
      alert(rowData);
      alert(user_id);
    });   

});

Comment: thats what i did.

Comment: you only should use this code: `$('#dataTables-docs tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){

  var user_id = $(this).val();
  alert(user_id);

});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133506/discussion-between-jc-john-and-cmedina).